# Angular databinding based on dataset rather than location

Tags: angularjs, parsing, data-binding, angularjs-scope, ng-options

I have a dropdown that should display a name underneath after the selection. However, the data is grabbing by where it is in the array instead of referencing the data around it.

Here is the plunker if you want to get straight to the example: http://plnkr.co/edit/8rfBM4Lz8C1jSQCoPAmL?p=preview

For an example, I have this in my controller which references a following dataset:

```
<select ng-model="defcom"
        ng-options="opt.DefCom as opt.DefCom for opt in acct_info | filter:{Req:'MUST'}:true" >
      </select>
       <p>Hello {{ acct_info[defcom-1].AcctName }}</p>
```

Then my data set:

```
$scope.acct_info = [
      {
        "Req": "MUST",
        "DefCom": "1",
        "AcctName": "ThisName"
      },
      {
        "Req": "NoMUST",
        "DefCom": "5",
        "AcctName": "ThisName2"
      },
      {
        "Req": "MUST",
        "DefCom": "4",
        "AcctName": "ThisName3"
      },
      {
        "Req": "MUST",
        "DefCom": "7",
        "AcctName": "ThisName4"
      }
    ];
```

But as you can see, if 4 is selected, Hello ThisName4 shows instead of its assigned "ThisName3" and when 7 is selected, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Do you want defcom variable to be binded to exactly DefCom value(1,5,4,7)? You can bind it to entire selected object.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets yes, I would like to do that. How does one do this? I've tried DefCom.AcctName but it came up empty.

Comment: Take a look at this
http://plnkr.co/edit/HB49wOh3Smj4F3vKPjDE?p=preview

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets This almost solves my problem, but changing ng-options has gotten rid of the default value I had set

Comment: Updated the same plunker